# chromium log in 404

Tags: browser, chromium

When I try to log in chromium, it navigate me to this page:

https://accounts.google.com/signin/chrome/sync?ssp=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

> 404. That’s an error.
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

I downloaded chromium from here: https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium

The download link: https://download-chromium.appspot.com

I want to log in and sync my settings from google-chrome. Is this possible?

chromium version 81.0.4009.0

Comment: https://accounts.google.com/signin/chrome/sync?ssp=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F works for me. Is there a black space after the last character? Yes, you can sync your Chrome settings into Chromium.

Comment: @K7AAY Thanks for the reply. But the link gives me a 404 error as the question mentioned.

Comment: Suggest you report the bug at https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines since I can't replicate it.